# How to open a text file in read-only mode means there i can not perform write?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying it too much time but can not achieve the goal. File is opened but its opened in write mode.

Code-
in txtpath.text, I am passing the path of the text:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileObj= new System.IO.FileInfo(txtPath.Text);

fileObj.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileObj.FullName);
```

Comment: why are you using `Process.Start` for opening a file in an ASP.NET application?

Comment: I'm with Yahia here... something with this seems very wrong. You aren't "reading" the file at all, you are telling window to "execute" the file, and it will then try to open it in the default editor. But that makes no sense in an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 2):

use the [File.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) method

```
 string sFilename = "myfile.txt";
 FileStream SR = File.OpenRead(sFilename);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Opening a file to only read it's contents:**

```
    // Open the stream and read it back.
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path)) 
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

        while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
        }
    }
```

More about `File.OpenRead`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx

**Setting a file's `ReadOnly` attribute and executing it:**

```
File.SetAttributes(txtPath.Text, File.GetAttributes(txtPath.Text) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(txtPath.Text);
```